# Trouble recognizing one word intents

Tags: nlp, wit.ai

I'm using wit to recognize different intents in a retail context. Some of them trigger (successfully) FAQ answers, other initiate a business logic.

Surprisingly, I'm having a lot of trouble with the most basics conversational intents, like answering a `hi` or `hello`. Specially if they come as a single word (it doesn't get `hi` or `hello` but it successfully returns the correct intent for `hi buddy` or `hey dude`). Obviously there's a high chance that the first thing an user would say is just a simple `hello`, any of you found the same issue? Any guidance on that?

It is actually the first time I experience this issue, and I haven't heard about it. Could it be related to the increasing number of intents created (now 15+)? I'm using `trait` as a search strategy.

Greetings intent

[image: Greetings intent here]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: For our chatbot (NodeJS), we manually handle greetings. We check to see it's a greeting before passing it on to wit.

Comment: Thanks Bcf, I was looking forward to use wit.ai for the greetings too since many times greetings come with a question ('Hi how can i solve this issue with my order?) so I wanted wit to make the call and recognize in this sentence that there was an issue with the order rather than just greet the user. Anyway, it is helpful since the only issue right now is with one word greetings (such as 'hi' and 'hello') that we indeed can capture before sending to wit.